# Alternative SQL ANSI for TOP WITH TIES

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have two tables:

product

- id_product
- description
- price
- id_category

category

- id_category
- description

I would like to know the categories that have more products. For example, the category food has 10 products and the eletronics too. They are the same.

Now I'm using SQL Server and I'm using TOP WITH TIES.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES p.id_category, COUNT(*) as amount FROM product p 
JOIN category c ON p.id_category = c.id_category
GROUP BY p.id_category
ORDER BY amount
```

Is there another way to solve this with good performance?
I tried also with DENSE_RANK where the position is = 1. 
It also works.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT p.id_category, COUNT(*) as amount, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)  position FROM product p 
JOIN category c ON p.id_category = c.id_category
GROUP BY p.id_category
) rnk
WHERE rnk.position = 1
```

But I want this solution in SQL ANSI.

I tried using MAX(COUNT(*)) but it doesn't work.

Is there a general solution? Is This solution better than using TOP WITH TIES?

Comment: When you used `MAX(COUNT(*))`, did you try using it in  `HAVING`?

Comment: Dense rank _is_ part of the ANSI SQL standard, and it would only not be available if you were using MySQL or a small handful of other databases.  What is the problem with relying on dense rank?

Comment: I tried using a SUBSELECT ON Having to get the max. But should I repeat the code?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that! I thought DENSE_RANK was only a SQL SERVER function. But there's no another way using subquery? I would like to compare the performance.

Comment: `dense_rank()` is the way to go. It's **not** a SQL Server specific function, e.g. Oracle has had it ages before SQL Server even knew it existed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a third option for SQL Server:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT p.id_category, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM product p 
    INNER JOIN category c
        ON p.id_category = c.id_category
    GROUP BY p.id_category
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cnt = (SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM cte);
```

If you also cannot rely on CTEs being available, you can easily enough just inline the CTE into the query.  From a performance point of view, `DENSE_RANK` would probably outperform my answer.

With the CTE removed this becomes:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT p.id_category, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM product p 
    INNER JOIN category c
        ON p.id_category = c.id_category
    GROUP BY p.id_category
)
WHERE cnt = (SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM (
                 SELECT p.id_category, COUNT(*) AS cnt
                 FROM product p 
                 INNER JOIN category c
                     ON p.id_category = c.id_category
                 GROUP BY p.id_category
            ));
```

This query would even run on MySQL.  As you can see, the query is ugly, which is one reason why things like CTE and analytic functions were introduced into the ANSI standard.

Comment: It's also a good answer. But it's not ANSI, right? I would like to know a way using only subquery or another ansi way. Thanks

Comment: @OnScreen Let me remove the CTE.

Comment: It really works I was thinking in something like this. I think it's really the best solution using only subquery. I tested and the top with ties and this one have the same perfomance. 50%. Thanks, man!!!

Comment: @OnScreen: the first query **is** ANSI SQL